# chromedriver hanging in headless mode when switching handles

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to switch handles (windows) in selenium using chromedriver.

For instance, a link is identified on a page and clicked, a new window is opened with the url, then I am switching to the window that was just opened:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

however, when I try this in headless mode, selenium seems to hang and not process anything further.

Anyone have a work around?

Comment: have you checked the number of windows before switching, did you got any error message?

Comment: @supputuri the code runs in non-headless mode fine, I have not checked to see if the new window was opened in headless mode. No error message, selenium just hangs until I force exit

Comment: Can you print the len of handle, before switching? That will give idea if the window is loaded and ready for switch.

Comment: of handle[1] ??

Comment: `print(len(driver.window_handles))`

Comment: returns 2......

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193606/discussion-between-supputuri-and-dataviews).